# magento2 file upload Pdf not working

Tags: magento2, controllers, file-upload

i have create controller for save data but i have not save **pdf file** 
 so please help me how can fix this issue
Thanks!!

```
<?php 
public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    try{
        $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('media/');        

        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'file']);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $result = $uploader->save($target);
        if ($result['file']) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('File has been successfully uploaded')); 
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
        '*/*/upload', ['_secure'=>$this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
    );            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to only my function replace to your function  and after check it

```
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    try{
        $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('mycustomfolder/');        
        /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'file']);
        /** Allowed extension types */
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['pdf','pptx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'flash', 'mp3', 'docx', 'doc', 'zip', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'ini', 'readme', 'avi', 'csv', 'txt', 'wma', 'mpg', 'flv', 'mp4']);
        /** rename file name if already exists */
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        /** upload file in folder "mycustomfolder" */
        $result = $uploader->save($target);
        if ($result['file']) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('File has been successfully uploaded')); 
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
        '*/*/upload', ['_secure'=>$this->getRequest()->isSecure()]
    );            
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh this code work for me